# Do I need to use nodejs https module if my host provider provides TLS Certificates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

It is my first time of deploying an application that would be used  in real life and it uses stripe api for handling payments. I would like to deploy the nodejs application on render host. Render said this: "All applications and static sites hosted on Render come with fully managed and free TLS certificates. There is no setup and you don’t need to do anything at all; everything just works out of the box..." I want to know if I would still need to use the nodejs https module instead of http module to handle the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are used as a sort of secret key to enable encryption. If they only provide a certificate, then you are still responsible for doing the actual encryption.

IF they provide TLS termination (load balancer / proxy), then you don't. If you're not certain you can always just test this.

Comment: How can I test it, or can you refer me to an article that can help me on that